# Referencing the index of a generic type in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, type-inference, typescript-generics

I'm trying to create generic message types, with ever-narrower types, the most narrow of-which is actually inferred during the calling of a function or creation of a class.

Take this code:

```js
type MessageHeaderType = 'REQUEST'|'RESPONSE'|'UPDATE'|'ERROR'|'EVENT'

type UnknownRecord = object

interface Message<MessageBody = UnknownRecord> {

  header: {
    id?: string
    type: MessageHeaderType
  },
  body: MessageBody

}

interface MessageUpdate<MessageBody = MessageUpdateBody> extends Message<MessageBody> {

  header: {
    id: string
    type: 'UPDATE'
  }
}

interface MessageUpdateBody {

  code: string
  data?: UnknownRecord

}
```

This works nicely and I can create a `MessageUpdate` easily:

```js
const ExampleMessageUpdate: MessageUpdate = {

  header: {
    id: '123',
    type: 'UPDATE'
  },
  body: {
    code: 'SOME_UPDATE',
    data: {
      foo: 'bar'
    }
  }
} // <== All good!
```

The problem comes when I allow a user of said code to generate their own message update body "on the fly" (still compile-time, obvs!). The below code does not let me index the generic that is passed in their implementation of a particular `MessageUpdate` type:

```js
function createMessage<ThisMessageUpdateBody>(code: string, data?: ThisMessageUpdateBody['data']): MessageUpdate<ThisMessageUpdateBody> {

  const message: MessageUpdate<ThisMessageUpdateBody> = {
    header: {
      id: '123',
      type: 'UPDATE'
    },
    body: {
      code,
      data
    }
  }

  return message
  
}
```

I get the error on the function parameters:

> Type '"data"' cannot be used to index type 'ThisMessageUpdateBody'

How can I achieve a further narrowing of this type, in the same manner, without an error?

Comment: You should probably limit `ThisMessageUpdateBody` to something that is guaranteed to have `data`, e.g. `createMessage<ThisMessageUpdateBody extends { data: any }>`, otherwise it's not clear, that `ThisMessageUpdateBody['data']` exists.

Comment: Ah! Yes, I see now that MessageUpdate should contain at least ‘code’ and ‘data’ within its’ ‘body’. Not sure how I missed that. Thanks! Although I’m guessing I structured it this way such that I could still dictate an entire MessageBody, so your suggestion works better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update**

Here's a slightly changed version to accommodate OP's comment.

If using an object as a single parameter of the function is not an option, then at least I would go with type aliases for keeping it safe and also staying away from string indexes.

```js
type BodyCodeType = string;
type BodyDataType = UnknownRecord;

interface MessageUpdateBody {
  code: BodyCodeType;
  data?: BodyDataType;
}

interface MessageUpdate<MessageBody = MessageUpdateBody>
  extends Message<MessageBody> {
  header: {
    id: string;
    type: 'UPDATE';
  };
}

function createMessage<ThisMessageUpdateBody extends MessageUpdateBody>(
  code: BodyCodeType,
  data: BodyDataType
): MessageUpdate<ThisMessageUpdateBody> {
  const message: MessageUpdate<ThisMessageUpdateBody> = {
    header: {
      id: '123',
      type: 'UPDATE',
    },
    body: {
      code,
      data,
    } as ThisMessageUpdateBody,
  };

  return message;
}

const customMsg = createMessage('test_code', { foo: 'bar' });

console.log(customMsg); // OK
```

Btw, you still need the `as ThisMessageUpdateBody` cast, otherwise the compiler will get confused on the `body`:

[image]

---

Personally I would rely on data inference from the actual template type, and so I would use an object for the function parameter. Like this:

```js
function createMessage<ThisMessageUpdateBody extends MessageUpdateBody>({
  code,
  data,
}: ThisMessageUpdateBody): MessageUpdate<ThisMessageUpdateBody> {
  const message: MessageUpdate<ThisMessageUpdateBody> = {
    header: {
      id: '123',
      type: 'UPDATE',
    },
    body: {
      code,
      data,
    } as ThisMessageUpdateBody,
  };

  return message;
}

const customMsg = createMessage({
  code: 'test_code',
  data: { foo: 'bar' },
});
```

And not using strings for indexing is another win, because now if you change from `data` to `payload` inside `MessageUpdateBody`, it will throw a clear compile time error.

Comment: The problem with this is that ‘createMessage’ is actually sugar for a library which needs to have code and data as separate parameters in the function, for ease of use. So your method was my first choice but I’m bound by that limitation of making it user friendly.

Comment: @shennan I just updated my answer. Btw, you should add the detail/restriction from your comment into the actual question text, to give more context to others reading it.

Comment: Will do; I’m currently in transit so editing my main question will be tough. The issue with your update is now there is a disconnect between the ThisMessageUpdateBody passed by the user and the arguments. Meaning that the tooling will not hint them the required arguments for that particular argument. Unless I’m missing something?

Comment: The connection is still there, made by the type aliases and (most importantly) by the returned type, which is still using the template parameter.

```typescript
const customMsg1 = createMessage(123, 'as'); // Error: Argument of type 'number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.

const customMsg2 = createMessage('test_code', 'xyz'); // Error: Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'object'.

const customMsg3 = createMessage('test_code', { foo: 'bar' }); // OK
```

You can check it out here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-xbsdes

Comment: As far as I can see from my phone the connection is lost. Will check tomorrow on a proper machine so I can use VSCode and check the tooling. I’m the meantime, thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: This has indeed worked out as the best solution for my case. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

One way to refer the index of generic type is to create another generic and assign this generic as the type, so in your case it could be something like

```
function createMessage<ThisMessageUpdateBody extends MessageUpdateBody, Data extends ThisMessageUpdateBody['data']>(code: string, data?: Data): MessageUpdate<ThisMessageUpdateBody> {
    const body = {
        code,
        data
    };
  const message = {
    header: {
      id: '123',
      type: UPDATE as typeof UPDATE
    },
    body
  }

  return message
  
}
```

Although above snippets still throws an error because `ThisMessageUpdateBody` could be of any sub type of MessageUpdateBody i.e it could contains many other properties apart from `code` & `data` (below is the error).

```
Type '{ code: string; data: Data | undefined; }' is not assignable to type 'ThisMessageUpdateBody'.
      '{ code: string; data: Data | undefined; }' is assignable to the constraint of type 'ThisMessageUpdateBody', but 'ThisMessageUpdateBody' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'MessageUpdateBody'.(2322)
```

##### Suggestion 1:

`createMessage` to have `body` parameter instead of `code`& `data`

```
function createMessage<ThisMessageUpdateBody extends MessageUpdateBody= MessageUpdateBody>(body: ThisMessageUpdateBody): MessageUpdate<ThisMessageUpdateBody> {
  const message = {
    header: {
      id: '123',
      type: UPDATE as typeof UPDATE
    },
    body
  }

  return message
  
}
```

##### Suggestion 2:

instead of declaring generic type of messageBody `createMessage` could declare generic type of body `data`. This lets us fulfil the constraint that message body would always have two properties (`code: string` & `data: CustomData`)

```
// MessageBody declare generic for "body.data" type
interface MessageUpdateBody<MessageBodyData = UnknownRecord> {

  code: string
  data?: MessageBodyData

}

function createMessage<MessageBodyData = UnknownRecord>(code: string, data: MessageBodyData): MessageUpdate<MessageUpdateBody<MessageBodyData>> {
  const message = {
    header: {
      id: '123',
      type: UPDATE as typeof UPDATE
    },
    body: {
        code,
        data
    }
  }

  return message
  
}
```

[Above TS snippet playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEHUFMBsGMHsC2lQBd5oBYoCoE8AHSAZVgCcBLA1UABWgEM8BzM%20AVwDsATAGiwoBnUENANQAd0gAjQRVSQAUCEmYKsTKGYUAbpGF4OY0BoadYKdJMoL%20gzAzIoz3UNEiPOofEVKVqAHSKymAAmkYI7NCuqGqcANag8ABmIjQUXrFOKBJMggBcISGgoAC0oACCbvCwDKgU8JkY7p7ehCTkVDQS2E6gnPCxGcwmZqDSTgzxxWWVoASMFmgYkAAeRJTInN3ymj4d-jSCeNsMq-wuoPaOltigAKoASgAywhK7SbGQZIIz5VWCFzSeCrZagNYbChbHaxUDcCjJZLfSDbExIAgUdxkUBIursJzCFJtXydajBBCcQQ0MwAUVWDEQC0gADVHBQGNJ3KAALygABEAAkYNAMOB4GRonzFBTBPB3AERcwABS0%20mM9ysygc9wASmCKhwzQ8ZC8iHFzmB7BoXzcZmY7AYzEg-Fg0HUiQ58D0Ii8fLpDKZgj5SWxfPADlQAHJhAA5SASPlBFQAeS%20ZHegmdWkgR1QjgUrmkeFATjNOmGWH0KAQiGhwkuNok4uiIgMHGxCyYrA4PCC0saVIetAAIhUcDSefz7iOxzS%20QBuYKodqgACy%20kBTqFDG4332k8jjxpAEV7jTiDhIwAfQ-n2jJmPEGnXtDtInT0fj0A3mmPR7Jx5r0jGlmRpGNLyXFd7gSAYJE4R5IAQMhXF5eBpAAK0Q1BggyBQyGSBglnXQRN0gAAeYjSIAIXgbhi15aD4lg%20DEPFbgAD5QAAb2CEpsB3b58m4xQShKChuAAfiEqlKE4ZgRNE5ciCEyjHUgbddzIfYFIAX14BTgTolSNzUmi6OCHScO2b4CKIkynXuAhuDqcjVKdMy8E4tYFB4YQ3Nc%20zIA8zieIU-jNKEnjRJEbhpNQWT5OipTICE5L3xncddMUSzFFwmzCJQfzHOchQPIowKPOHOpxAYmD4DghCkI44SFIQXc4oShSSoYKS1wq2i8CqvMLOCZIuFgepGhMSYFH8sicDUQQiqclyPPBVYfO4PzAuK1aBt5ZaSqCgb2KVQy8CEhahEOva6J1YySLU3aFHmxabtKk7hJKGUaGQR6nUnKLRPCwSvuimKhMjABGAAmABmSN9PB19lKHT8JwYYQ0tSD9ZwUko9Px8YBqyhSnFQfFTUChTstG8bJq8cgPFmwLwF2IaGHK-7jrojnJ0Y5jGrY062pSq54uGfhuoe6iBo5%206%20u556AqVlaPrornZd56r2JC1qB1%20wLAaJkGyEiomxNi0BofhxGLZRsXca-TGHfS9GicJ6LzvN5Hvto517ZKbqPdJkpycp0A-tImnLJKIA)